# Flutter: How can I limit the number of times a user can click on a button in a given time period?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a button that displays a prompt in a snackbar. Right now if I press the button rapidly, say 50 times, the snackbar appears for a few seconds, then again, and then again, till it's shown 50 times. How can I prevent this?

Here's my code-

```
          actions: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                elevation: 7,
                color: Colors.black26,
                child: Text('Button'),
                onPressed: () {
                  _scaffoldKey.currentState
                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Welcome")));
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
```

Comment: Have you tried applying a BLoC method with timer to the button?

Comment: @fish-like-mammal No I haven't tried it. Can you post an elaborate answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to solve this problem. One is, you can easily prevent multiple taps for a while.

```
           bool _enabled = true;


           onPressed: !_enabled
            ? null 
            : () {
              setState(() => _enabled = false);
              _scaffoldKey.currentState
                  .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Welcome")));
             
               // Enable it after 1s.
               Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () => setState(() => _enabled = true));
            },
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution! Although you mixed up the trues and falses you should edit that.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [tap_debouncer](https://pub.dev/packages/tap_debouncer) package to get rid of your problem. Just use cooldown feature to disable the button press for a limited period time so to prevent multiple taps. There are also many other features provided by the package which can be used to solve your problem.